KeyDB : Vector Search and Search modules
We are trying to find a reasonable substitute for Redis Cache.
I am looking at KeyDB for possible replacement.
However, I am unable to learn if we would be able to run following two modules in KeyDB.

Vector Search
The Search Module

Does anyone know if we would be able to run these two modules in KeyDB?
Many thanks,
JE
I tried going thorugh the documentation pages, and Modules API Reference but I couldn't find these two.
I tried searching on web but didn't any references, so far.

It's a single module, but that aside, why are you looking for an alternative?

@PieterCailliau - are these modules available in KeyDB? - Looking for alternative because of recent license changes.

Why does that change anything? https://www.infoworld.com/article/3714688/the-bizarre-defense-of-trillion-dollar-cabals.html

@OfirLuzon - I would go through the article. However, my question still remains :-) Thanks.

I've heard of people using RediSearch with KeyDB, I can't speak to how well it would work, it's not officially supported but it might work. I'd be remiss if I didn't point out that the RediSearch Module uses the same SSPL/RSALv2 License that Redis does, so it would still apply. I'd be skeptical as to whether the new license impacts you (unless you are trying to build a competitor to Redis?) see the original article explaining the changes : https://redis.io/blog/redis-adopts-dual-source-available-licensing/

@java_enthu also interested in this. I am looking for the timeseries module support. DId you find out if the 2 search modules you were looking for are supported and also do you happen to know if timeseries is supported? I too searched everywhere and nothing on timeseries

posted about the redis timeseries module here https://stackoverflow.com/q/78538635/5442187

no idea about timeseries data module with keydb @uberrebu
