Does KeyDB Officially Support Redis Timeseries Module
Does anyone know if KeyDB https://docs.keydb.dev/, now under Snap support timeseries module from redis stack?
I currently use the timeseries with the redis stack and want to switch to KeyDB because of the multi-master support and better multi-threaded support and ease of management for clustered redis drop-in replacement
Searched online and could not find anything with support for timeseries
Only thing that came close is this thing https://hub.docker.com/layers/kmeinster/keydb-timeseries/latest/images/sha256-b336f4ece6828acda62daf5d7fe581015287bda43bf5db8d8f538b5cf3ed6dd9
